# Clerk back end API always gives status code of 401

Tags: next.js, fetch-api, clerk

I'm trying to fetch a specific user with the Clerk backend API. Here's the endpoint: `https://api.clerk.com/v1/users/{user_id}`. I'm using the Nextjs fetch function to get the data:

```
try {
            const userProfileData = await fetch(
                `https://api.clerk.com/v1/users/${user}`,
                {
                    method: "GET",
                    mode: "no-cors",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    },
                }
            );
            console.log(userProfileData);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
```

This code returns status code 401 with a response for Clerk:

```
Response {type: 'opaque', url: '', redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}
body
: 
(...)
bodyUsed
: 
false
headers
: 
Headers
[[Prototype]]
: 
Headers
ok
: 
false
redirected
: 
false
status
: 
0
statusText
: 
""
type
: 
"opaque"
url
: 
""
[[Prototype]]
: 
Response
```

It also produces two Nextjs errors:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
```

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: There was an error while hydrating this Suspense boundary. Switched to client rendering.
```

I've also tried wrapping the code with `useEffect` to no avail. Other Clerk APIs return similar responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to configure the middleware to recognize your routes. Doc for Clerk with Next.js:

https://clerk.com/docs/references/nextjs/auth-middleware

With the proper config, your app will know which routes are for the API and not `401` those.

Please start with this guide, and begin with the *most simple* implementation of `authMiddleware`. Rule of thumb: keep it simple (only use options if necessary) and stick to the doc-examples.

*You probably won't need the `next-intl` and `beforeAuth` bits, but you can think about those for later.*

Focus on the `afterAuth` implementation, be sure to set your `apiRoutes` and `publicRoutes` options, and possibly `ignoredRoutes` option if necessary. Get it working in basic form and then add a feature at a time so know if and what breaks.

Here's the final/compiled example from the Clerk docs - which you may work yourself up to by the end, and which also may need some adjustments for your app.

`/src/middleware.ts:`

```js
import { authMiddleware, redirectToSignIn } from '@clerk/nextjs';
 
export default authMiddleware({
  apiRoutes: ['/(api|trpc)(.*)'], // Per `matcher` - `publicRoutes` override this
  publicRoutes: ['/sign-in', '/sign-up'],
  afterAuth(auth, req, evt) {
    // Allow matched api/public requests
    if (auth.isApiRoute || auth.isPublicRoute) {
      return response
    }
    // handle users who aren't authenticated
    if (!auth.userId && !auth.isPublicRoute) {
      return redirectToSignIn({ returnBackUrl: req.url });
    }
    // Ex. // redirect them to organization selection page
    // if (auth.userId && !auth.orgId && req.nextUrl.pathname !== "/org-selection"){
    //   const orgSelection = new URL('/org-selection', req.url)
    //   return NextResponse.redirect(orgSelection)
    // }
  }
});


export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)', '/', '/(api|trpc)(.*)'],
};
```